# Write in a cell full time

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I have a variable `time` which contains string with time in format `h:m:s.ms`

I was trying to write in a cell this time, but when I open excel I saw smth like `12:34:14 PM`.
But I want to see `12:34:14.1354`

How can I solve this problem?

```
var line = "2019-07-18 11:07:42.6101";
var time = line.Substring(11, 13);

worksheet.Cell(row, column).Value = time;
```

Comment: You need to set the cell's display format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
worksheet.Cell(row,column).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "h:mm:ss.SSSS";
```

I am not 100% sure whether the format string is correct. Maybe you start trying out by leaving away the milliseconds part. Compare this: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Data-Types

**UPDATE:** Reflecting anthony14's comment to the answer, the correct code is

```
worksheet.Cell(row,column).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "h:mm:ss.ms";
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but it doesn't work correctly, now I saw ######

Comment: adjusting the column width does not help?

Comment: So, yeap, you should expand column and I changed a little bit your code, cause in ms I've got duplication and it was equal sec.
I changed to "h:mm:ss.ms" and now it works great. Thanks for help. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Use format string like "h:mm:ss.000" with zeroes count from 1 to 3. It is worked for me:

```
worksheet.Cell(row,column).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "h:mm:ss.000"
```